# Best practice for application installation with powershell scripts from shared domain

Tags: powershell

Please could someone outline best practice when running a powershell batch script for application installations when deploying. Should individual application installation files be available temporary locally or can they be run from a shared domain folder ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, always copy locally.